# Checking for offline in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

navigator.onLine is true for 1st time loading.It is false while refreshing the page when network is online in typescript.pls help me

```
var online = navigator.onLine; 
if(online) { 
this._service.log(online); 
return this.CallGetArticleDetailsFromService(); 
} 
else{ 
this._service.log(online); 
return this.CallGetArticleFromIndexedDb();
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: hi,below is my code var online = navigator.onLine;
    if(online)
    {
      this._service.log(online);
      return this.CallGetArticleDetailsFromService();
    }
    else{
      this._service.log(online);
      return this.CallGetArticleFromIndexedDb();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be obvious but remember about import

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

I would do something like that:

```
online: Observable<boolean>;

constructor() {
  this.online = Observable.merge(
    Observable.of(navigator.onLine),
    Observable.fromEvent(window, 'online').mapTo(true),
    Observable.fromEvent(window, 'offline').mapTo(false)
  )
}
```

than your code

```
if(online) { 
this._service.log(online); 
return this.CallGetArticleDetailsFromService(); 
} 
else{ 
this._service.log(online); 
return this.CallGetArticleFromIndexedDb();
 }
```

Comment: Hi,In console.log I am getting "Observable {_isScalar: false, source: ArrayObservable, operator: MergeMapOperator}" not offline or online

Comment: You need to subscribe to the observable and pass a callback that processes emitted values. `this.serviceName.functionName().subscribe(val => console.log(val));`

Comment: sorry i am not getting.I am new to angular2.I need to check for offline in ngoninit of app.component.I wrote above logic in component constructor.Then which method i need to call from service

Comment: In your component you should subscribe to observable like this `this.online.subscribe(val => console.log(val));`

Comment: Hi,Its also like navigator.Online.Since it gives false .sometimes while system is in  online

Comment: This is very simple solution. I supposed more solid solution need some more research. You have to investigate it in depth.